# Error when assigning values to members in structures using scanf

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list using C. This is the code that I have now.

```
//fig 12_4.c

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct gradeNode{
    char lastName[20];
    double grade;
    struct gradeNode *nextPtr;
};


void insert(GradeNodePtr);

int main(void)
{
    //part a
    struct gradeNode *startPtr = NULL;

    //part b
    struct gradeNode *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));
    startPtr = newPtr; 

    // checking to see if memory was allocated properly 
    if(newPtr != NULL)
    {
        newPtr->grade = 91.5;
        strcpy(newPtr->lastName,"Jones");
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    }

    //part c
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
      struct gradeNode *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(GradeNode));

      if(newPtr != NULL)
      {
        printf("Please Type A grade: ");
        scanf("%lf",newPtr->grade);
        printf("Please Enter a LastName: ");
        scanf("%s",newPtr->lastName);
        puts("");
      }
      else
      {
        puts("No memory available. Critical Error!");
      }
    }
}
```

If you look at the for loop under the comment labeled **part c** you may be able to find my error. After the **scanf("%lf",newPtr->grade);** line of code is ran the execution process stop. Therefore, the scanf function to enter lastname is never reached and the for loop doesn't loop 3 times. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You prototype the function `insert` as if you will pass it one ptr. It is declared `void`, so it will not return any value. You will need to pass `insert` both the current head of the LL **and** the new node for this to progress. Do you want to "push" nodes in reverse order? Or do you want to always append to the tail of an existing list? That, and the problem @Chris's answer addressed.

Comment: You allocate new nodes in your loop but you never link them together. Also shadowing existing variables by defining another one with same name is generally discouraged and forbidden by some coding guidelines.

Comment: @Gerhardh Well spotted! There'd be no way to refer to the "shadowed" variable within the code block. Ah... The wonders of copy/paste software _development_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` expects to receive pointers. `newPtr->grade` is *not* a pointer.

```
scanf("%lf", &newPtr->grade);
```

As always, you should check the return from `scanf` to ensure the data was successfully read.